# Querying Dynamics CRM 2013 Online

Tags: api, crm, microsoft-dynamics

I found a link with a how-to query the Dynamics CRM for 2011.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334767.aspx

Does anybody know if it works with 2013?

Tks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that works for CRM 2013 as well.

Comment: Andrii tks for the answer. Did you know how to get the clients names and ids from crm using javascript?

Comment: Do you mean Account entity? Recheck following url [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328025.aspx).

Comment: I want to list all custumers (name and id) in this CRM.

Comment: You should recheck [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg985387.aspx)